# RegExp how to deal with RegExp When you call the construcor?

Tags: regex, actionscript-3

I've different results if I use a RegExp pattern and when I use a new RegExp pattern...
I'm a noob with RegExp.
So

```
import flash.display.SimpleButton;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.Graphics;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.ui.ContextMenu;

    var myString1:String = "Sharsks in the sea";
    var pattern1:RegExp = new RegExp("^\s*|\s*$","gim");
    var pattern2:RegExp = new RegExp("\s*|\s*$","gim");
    var pTest:RegExp = /\s*|\s*$/gim;
    var result1:String = myString1.replace(/^\s*|\s*$/gim,"_");
    var result2:String = myString1.replace(pattern1,"_");
    var result3:String = myString1.replace(/\s*|\s*$/gim,"_");
    var result4:String = myString1.replace(pattern2,"_");
    var result5:String = myString1.replace(pTest,"_");

    trace(result1);
    trace(result2);
    trace(result3);
    trace(result4);
    trace(result5);

    outputs : 
    _Sharsks in the sea_
    _harsks in the sea_
    _S_h_a_r_s_k_s__i_n__t_h_e__s_e_a_
    __h_a_r__k__ _i_n_ _t_h_e_ __e_a_
    _S_h_a_r_s_k_s__i_n__t_h_e__s_e_a_
```

Can anyone tell me the difference between new operator and a logical RegExp pattern.

I know that is a very stupid question, so pardon me, but I'm confused...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The RegExp class lets you work with regular expressions, which are patterns that you can use to perform searches in strings and to replace text in strings.
>   You can create a new RegExp object by using the new RegExp() constructor or by assigning a RegExp literal to a variable:

```
var pattern1:RegExp = new RegExp("test-\\d", "i");
var pattern2:RegExp = /test-\d/i;
```

From [adobe](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/RegExp.html#includeExamplesSummary)

In other words, they are equivalent.

Comment: Thank you so much @NealDavis (upvoted) but why did I get a different output  with trace(result4); and trace(result5); ? Is there a way to figure me that easily?
I will try this tomorrow! Perhaps it will make sense immediately. (I hope it) ;)

Comment: I think you may need to put a forward slash in front of the second back slash in the second one.